Error saving a tess object as shapefile in R with sf::st_write
I'm using the spatstat package to create a hexagonal tessellation over a specified area and count points within each hexagon. After that, I want to save the tessellation as a shapefile for use in GIS.
How can I convert the tess object to sf or another compatible format so I can save it as a shapefile? Any guidance would be much appreciated!
Below is the code for a specific dataset which unfortunately isn't publicly available, but the plot is shown and it is the object QC_empresastur_hex that should be converted to sf format for subsequent export as shapefile.
library(spatstat)
hexagonos <- hextess (win_natales, 1000)
QC_ empresastur_hex <- quadratcount(empresastur_ppp, tess = hexagonos)
plot (empresastur_ppp, main = "Conteo de empresas por hexágonos", cols = "orange")
plot(QC_empresastur_hex, add = TRUE, cex = 1)



Please edit your question to make it reproducible. Also, please include the error message. Do not post code as picture. I have edited your question. Please specify the libraries needed to run your code as well. Unfortunately, I do not see where the code matches the described problem. I voted to close your question as it lacks a lot of details.

In case the question is reopened I can post a reproducible solution based on a built-in dataset in spatstat.

Here is an example using a built-in dataset:
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
hex <- hextess(Window(chorley), s = 4)
counts <- quadratcount(chorley, tess = hex)
plot(counts)


hex_sf_list <- lapply(tiles(hex), st_as_sf)
hex_sf <- Reduce(rbind, hex_sf_list)
counts_sf <- cbind(counts = as.integer(counts), hex_sf)
plot(counts_sf)


